# Инициировать программу как новое приложение Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно было сделать похожую программу, и я скопировал её папку и переименовал её в манифесте. При установке она заменяет первую программу. Как изменить параметры программ, чтобы они определялись как разные и не заменяли друг друга?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно поменять `applicationId` в `build.gradle` модуля